# How do I run the same linux command in more than one tab/shell simultaneously?

Tags: linux, multithreading, shell

Is there any tool/command in Linux that I can use to run a command in more than one tab simultaneously? I want to run the same command: *./myprog argument1 argument2* simultaneously in more than one shells (I want to increase this so as to put my code under stress later on) to check if the mutexes are working fine in a threaded program.

I am kind of looking for something like what wall does. I can think of using tty's, but that just seems like a lot of pain if I have to scale this to many more shells.

Comment: I've done it with `tmux` commands, but my code was pretty nasty since I was splitting panes, rather than using windows, which is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do something like

```
for i in {1..100}
do
    ./myprog argument1 argument2 &
done
```

This is in case the shell is bash. You can look into other looping constructs in case of other shells.

Comment: Ummmm... This is running the same command multiple times in the same shell. (Sequentially no less.)

Comment: Why the requirement for multiple shells? You can do `/bin/sh -c ./myprog argument1 argument2 &` in case you want separate shells. And they are parallel since the & forces them to background.

Comment: Ah I didnt see the &. But that still does not help. Lets just say that I want to see what each command line user will see if they entered the command from their individual shells and hence I want to see it from different shells/tabs of the terminal.

Comment: This will garble the output. Not really optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Running the jobs asynchronously with redirected output is the simplest solution, but if you really want each process to run in its own terminal, a good option is to use a terminal emulator like `screen` or `tmux`.  For example:

```
yes | sed 5q | while read k; do  # iterate 5 times
  tmux new-session -d 'sh -c "/path/to/myprog arg1 arg2; sh"'&
done
```

The trailing `sh` causes the session to remain alive after myprog terminates, and the intial `yes` pipeline is used instead of `seq` since it works where `seq` is not available (there are lots of ways to iterate!)

Once the sessions are running, you can attach to them individually to view the output.  (See `tmux` documentation for details.)

Answer (score 1):

Install the moreutulis package (with non-GNU parallel) or, preferably, GNU parallel (often packaged separately; SUSE calls it gnu_parallel, Ubuntu and RedHat call it parallel) so you can use parallel. Then figure out how to specify the terminal your command runs in. For example

```
parallel yourscript -- tty1 tty2 pts6
```

Then you just have to figure out how to write "yourscript" to take the tty to run on as an argument, which is a separate question. :)

Comment: Just be aware, that moreutils is not GNU, and the parallel in moreutils is not GNU Parallel, but another program.

Comment: @OleTange Good catch. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using gnome terminal, try this one

```
gnome-terminal --maximize --tab-with-profile=default -e '/bin/sh -c ./myprog argument1 argument2' --tab-with-profile=default -e '/bin/sh -c ./myprog argument1 argument2' --tab-with-profile=default -e '/bin/sh -c ./myprog argument1 argument2'
```

please check gnome-terminal [man page](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/gnome_terminal) for more options

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU Parallel's `--tmux --fg`:

```
parallel -j20 --tmux --fg echo doit {}\; sleep {} ::: {1..100}
```

Use <kbd>ctrl-b</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl-b</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> to cycle between the running terminals.

That way you can keep everything in a single window, but without the output from the jobs mixing.

Comment: Even though github says you wrote this feature almost a year later ;) , this is now the best solution. And I'm glad I was brought back here to learn that it exists. :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation when I was at college and I did something like this

```
for i in $(seq 1 10)
do
  xterm -e "./myprog argument1 argument2"&
done
```

This spawns 10 xterms each running your program in the background.

Answer (score 0):

From comments it seems you don't need stdin, do need stdout, don't want ptys, don't want `screen` or `tmux`.

Easy-peasy:

```
for seq in `seq 5`; do
        ./myprog argument1 argument2 >output$seq &
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could (ab)use [clusterssh](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/413853:managing-multiple-linux-servers-with-clusterssh) for that?

Answer (score -1):

Open a bunch of terminals, get everything set up, then hit ENTER really quickly in each terminal.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing that UNIX was made to avoid.

Comment: In "more than one tab"? I'm not sure Unix was even built with tabs in mind. Maybe he could use the curses library, but who uses that anymore? Is this part of a long term project? Or just a one-off kind of test he's doing?